# Conjunctions of disjunctions equivalent to disjunctions of conjunctions?

Tags: logic

For finite sets $I$, $J$ and formulas $A_{i, j}$ is this equivalence true?

$\bigwedge_{i\in I} \bigvee_{j\in J}A_{i, j} \equiv \bigvee_{j\in J}\bigwedge_{i\in I}A_{i, j} $

I tried it out with some examples and it seemed correct. How would prove that?

Answer (score 0):

LHS is "For all $i$ there is some $j$ such that $A_{i,j}$ holds":
everybody loves somebody.

RHS is "There is some $j$ such that, for all $i$, $A_{i,j}$ holds": 
somebody is loved by everybody.